# Bizarre Hair Render In Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I'm trying to do hair in cycles and everything is fine until I render.

Before:
[image]

But After a render:
[image]
The hair goes wild

I tried raising the hair off the scalp but it still goes wild, no idea what settings triggered this.

Comment: If you can post a .blend, that would be your best chance for figuring this out.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/q6czsqpkwkmffjx/Hairtest.blend

Comment: I've downloaded your blend... checking it out now.

Comment: Well, I messed with the blend a bit. It was bringing my work system to its knees, so I waited and tried it on my home machine. Took a long time to setup the BVH and finally start rendering, and then it crashed during render.

Comment: I turned down the sampling and finally got a render, and verified that my output matched yours (after the render the hair was all skeewompus). I went to the particles tab and clicked the 'Free Bake' button on your hair system, and then rebaked (took quite a while). After that the render looked much better. Try rebaking and see what you get.

Comment: I'm using blender 2.75 and I can't find a bake/cache option in the particles-hair tab.

Comment: All my particle tab options are shown in the first image

Comment: I'm also not using hair dynamics, should I turn that on then bake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-baking your particle cache. You may need to click 'free bake' first before 'bake' will become available. [image]

Comment: I also found my subsurf modifier made the hair wonky too.

Comment: @Laeh Tana So, are you back on track? Is the hair behaving properly?